# Where can I find Eclipse CDT's indexer?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, indexer

I put Linux kernel source codes in my removable hard disk. And I use Eclipse CDT to create indexer for source navigation. But I cannot find the indexer after several minutes indexing. I hope to put the indexer and all related files into the removable hard disk, so that I can use it anywhere.

Where is the indexer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use search and find it. It is here:

```
C:\Users\Tom\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core\linux-kernel.1421507248027.pdom
```

The file size is 835M.

```
C:\Users\Tom\workspace2
```

Above is my Eclipse CDT workspace. And I can use

```
Eclipse -> Switch Workspace
```

to point to my removable hard disk easily.